# css overlapping divs with content

Tags: html, css

how can i get these to not keep overlapping, I know why is it, because the convo-container doesnt have a height, if i give it a height all is fine but convo-right needs the height to be dependent on the content of it so convo-container does also. convo mains properties must remain the same. also I want to do it this way to give it easy width positioning. thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/mxadam/Zpz86/

css:

```
.convo-main {position: absolute; overflow-y: scroll; background-color: #fff; padding-bottom: 5px; top: 0; bottom: 50px;left:0; right: 0;}
.convo-container{left:0;right:0;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px;padding-top: 5px;background-color:#000;}
.convo-left{position: absolute;width: 32px;height: 32px;padding-left: 0px;}
.convo-right{position: absolute;left: 37px;right:0;padding-left:5px;vertical-align:top;}
```

html:

```
<div class="convo-main">

<div class="convo-container">
    <div class="convo-left"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/L/P/X/z/i/no-image-icon-md.png" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></div>
    <div class="convo-right">text can be any height</div>
    </div>

<div class="convo-container">
    <div class="convo-left"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/L/P/X/z/i/no-image-icon-md.png" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></div>
    <div class="convo-right">text can be any height</div>
    </div>

 <div class="convo-container">
    <div class="convo-left"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/L/P/X/z/i/no-image-icon-md.png" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></div>
    <div class="convo-right">text can be any height<br />text can be any height<br />text can be any height<br /></div>
    </div>

<div class="convo-container">
    <div class="convo-left"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/L/P/X/z/i/no-image-icon-md.png" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></div>
    <div class="convo-right">text can be any height<br />text can be any height<br />text can be any height<br />text can be any height<br /></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Try removing absolute positioning. This eliminates the flow of the doc, the container height will not change. If you want to use absolute positioning within the container, then the parent container will need `position:relative`.

Comment: Dont use `position:absolute;`

Comment: Ignore absolute positioning

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/Zpz86/1/ ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `position: relative` instead of absolute positioning.

According to what you are describing, this would involve changing the position relative for

```
.convo-left
.convo-right
```

And keep `.convo-main` positioned absolutely

http://jsfiddle.net/Zpz86/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use `float` instead of `position:absolute`, then you need to `clear` every floats inside the `.convo-container` (check in the demo: `clearfix` class) to get auto height dependent on your content.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Cy98P/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of fixing this problem.

You can change the position of both `.convo-left` and `.convo-right` from `position:absolute;` to `position:relative;`

or you could also go about the problem a different way and not use any positioning on the `.convo-left` and `.convo-right` classes. Instead you can set the width of the `.convo-container` to 100% and add `float:left;` to `.convo-container, .convo-left .convo-right`

Here is the CSS:

```
.convo-container{float:left;width:100%;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px;padding-top: 5px;background-color:red;}
.convo-left{width: 32px;height: 32px;float:left;}
.convo-right{float:left;padding-left:5px;vertical-align:top;}
```

Either should solve your problem,